# Efficient way of finding the number of decimals a double value has

Tags: java, double

I want to find an effiecient way of making sure that the number of decimal places in 
double is not more than three.

```
double num1 = 10.012; //True
double num2 = 10.2211; //False
double num2 = 10.2; //True
```

Currently, what I do is just use a regex split and count index of . like below.

```
String[] split = new Double(num).toString().split("\\.")
split[0].length() //num of decimal places
```

Is there an efficient or better way to do this since I'll be calling this 
function a lot?

Comment: I think you're in for trouble here since double is not an exact representation and 2.112 can end up 2.119999999. Aren't you better to use BigDouble?

Comment: An important distinction to make here: It's entirely possible for a `double` to contain a value that *mathematically* has a (say) non-zero value in the (say) hundred-thousandth place, but which *when converted to string* will not. Such is the joy of IEEE-754 double-precision binary floating point. The number of digits you get from the string representation is only as many as necessary to distinguish the value from its adjacent representable value.

Comment: @vikingsteve that's what I'm leaning towards but my main concern is with memory. As in how memory efficient is a BidDouble

Comment: What constraints do you have on the value range? On first glance, a mathematic solution may well be more memory-efficient, but could easily run into boundary issues.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder Honestly I'm not sure. I'm dealing with prices; For starters, I'll assume 0-200K

Comment: Are you doing this check a million times per second? You could always look at the string representation, thats O(n).

Comment: @KalebBlue: If you're dealing with prices, don't use `double`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a solution that will tell you that information in a way that will agree with the eventual result of converting the `double` to a string, then efficiency doesn't really come into it; you basically have to convert to string and check. The result is that it's entirely possible for a double to contain a value that mathematically has a (say) non-zero value in (say) the hundred-thousandth place, but which when converted to string will not. Such is the joy of IEEE-754 double-precision binary floating point: The number of digits you get from the string representation is only as many as necessary to distinguish the value from its adjacent representable value. From [the `Double` docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#toString-double-):

> How many digits must be printed for the fractional part of *m* or *a*? There must be at least one digit to represent the fractional part, and beyond that as many, but only as many, more digits as are needed to uniquely distinguish the argument value from adjacent values of type `double`. That is, suppose that *x* is the exact mathematical value represented by the decimal representation produced by this method for a finite nonzero argument *d*. Then *d* must be the `double` value nearest to *x*; or if two `double` values are equally close to *x*, then *d* must be one of them and the least significant bit of the significand of *d* must be `0`.

But if you're not concerned about that, and assuming limiting your value range to `long` is okay, you can do something like this:

```
private static boolean onlyThreePlaces(double v) {
    double d = (double)((long)(v * 1000)) / 1000;
    return d == v;
}
```

...which should have less memory overhead than a `String`-round-trip.

**However**, I'd be surprised if there weren't a fair number of times when that method and the result of `Double.toString(double)` didn't match in terms of digits after the decimal, for the reasons given above.

---

In a comment on the question, you've said (when I asked about the value range):

> Honestly I'm not sure. I'm dealing with prices; For starters, I'll assume 0-200K

Using `double` for financial values is usually not a good idea. If you don't want to use `BigDecimal` because of memory concerns, pick your precision and use `int` or `long` depending on your value range. For instance, if you only need to-the-penny precision, you'd use values multiplied by 100 (e.g., 2000 is Ⓠ20 [or whatever currency you're using, I'm using Ⓠ for [quatloos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Gamesters_of_Triskelion)]). If you need precision to thousanths of a penny (as your question suggests), then multiply by 100000 (e.g., 2000000 is Ⓠ20). If you need more precision, pick a larger multiplier. Even if you go to hundred-thousanths of a penny (muliplier: 10000000), with `long` you have a range of Ⓠ-922,337,203,685 to Ⓠ922,337,203,685.

This has the side-benefit that it makes this check easier: Just a straight `%`. If your multiplier is 10000000 (hundred-thousandths of a penny), it's just `value % 10000 != 0` to identify invalid ones (or `value % 10000 == 0` to identify valid ones).

```
long num1 = 100120000;  // 10.012   => true
                        // 100120000 % 10000 is 0 = valid
long num2 = 102211000;  // 10.2211  => false
                        // 102211000 % 10000 is 1000 = invalid
long num3 = 102000000;  // 10.2     => true
                        // 102000000 % 10000 is 0 = valid
```

Comment: should it be the opposite? if I use long with a 10000 multiplier making 50.0411 500411.
500411 % 10000 gives 411. How do I know it's more than 3 d.p.? Can you please explain? Thanks in advance for the helpShould be the op

Comment: @KalebBlue: Sorry, I was unclear. `value % 10000 > 0` means it's *in*valid. I've clarified and expanded above. :-) **And** it should have been `!=` because you could have negative values, and `-102211000 % 10000` is `-1000`, not `1000`. Sorry about that.